# How to add a super voices of menu containing some sub voices in WP?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I am pretty new in WP (I came from Joomla) and I am finding some difficulties to do the following operation in WP Main Menu.

If you go on this site you can easy understand what I need: http://www.saranistri.com/saranistriWPnew/

As you can see in this website there is to much main menu voices (and the Main Menu takes up too much space) so I want group some voices as sub voices into a main voices.

I want something like this Joomla Main Menu: http://lnx.erusma.org/en/ in which, for example, if you pass the mouse on the **Who We Are** voice you can say the subvoice. Can I do the same thing in WP?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

In the WP backend, try going to Appearance-->Menus and dragging the menu items that you want to become sub-menus underneath the corresponding main menu item. The sub-menu item box should be slightly indented to the right to indicate that it is a sub-menu item.